# Postgres partitioning options right now?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a task which would really benefit from implementing partitioned tables, but I am torn because Postgres 10 will be coming out relatively soon.

1. If I just build normal tables and handle the logic with Python format strings to ensure that my data is loaded to the correct tables, can I turn this into a partition easily later?
2. Can I upgrade Postgres 9.6 to 10 right now? Or is that not advisable?
3. Should I install an extension like pg_partman?

My format string approach would just create separate tables (f{server}*{source}*{%Y%m}) and then I would union them together I suppose. Hopefully, I could eventually create a master table though without tearing anything down.

Comment: What is wrong with 9.6 partitioning? Are you sure you understand Postgresql's partitioning?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto There's built-in partitioning in Pg 10. 9.6 doesn't have partitioning, you have to build it yourself, but you can of course use inheritance to support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pg 10 partitioning right now is functionally the same as 9.6, just with prettier notation. Pretty much anything you can do in Pg 10, you can also do in 9.6 with table-inheritance based partitioning, it's just not as convenient.

It looks like you may not have understood that table inheritance is used for partitioning in 9.6, since you refer to doing big `UNION`s. This is unnecessary, PostgreSQL does it for you if you do inheritance-based partitioning. You can also have triggers that route inserts into the parent table into child tables, though it's more efficient for the application to route tuples like you suggest, by inserting directly into partitions. This will also work in PostgreSQL 10.

Pg's new built-in partitioning doesn't yet offer any new features you can't get with inheritance, like support for unique constraints across partitions, FKs referencing partitioned tables, etc. So there's really no reason to wait.

Just study up on how to do partitioning on 9.6.

I don't know if you can convert 9.6-style manual partitioning into PostgreSQL 10 native partitioning without copying the data. Ask on the mailing list or post a new specific question.

That said... often when people think they need partitioning, they don't. How sure are you that it's worth it?

Comment: I meant to just have truly separate tables actually (no partitioning), and then union them together as needed. The data I am gather is about 2 million + rows per day, so I figured monthly partitions would make sense. The most recent data is used for visualizations and any ad hoc request is typically for some calendar month summary or extract.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good candidate for partitioning. Often people pop up here with "lots" of data ("tens of thousands of rows!!") they want to partition and optimise...

Comment: I implemented the inheritance and everything is up and running just fine. Thanks a bunch.